# Save website containing javascript after it was interpreted

Tags: browser, html, javascript

There's a website I want to save that contains javascript (if that helps, the site is vyou.com; here's a link to [Andrew W. K.'s](http://vyou.com/andrewwk) user page) which updates the contents of what the user sees on the website. What I would like to do is save the site once the list of links to a user's video answers is fully expanded. I do not intend to also save the videos those links lead to, I just want to save the state my browser is in. What browser I use doesn't matter to me.

Has anyone done something similar or knows how to do achieve this?

Comment: [Archive.is](https://archive.is) does a reasonably good job of archiving things for you. =)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are (at least) two reasons that your saved file will not look exactly like the live website you saved:

1. Some or many of the links to images on the page could be "relative" links. Similarly, links to ".css" and ".js" files on the page could be "relative" links.
2. Some links to images and other files can be contained inside these ".css" and ".js" files.

For example, lets say you look at a page:

```
http://example.com/something/index.php
```

On that page, is a "relative" link to an image file:

```
"../images/picture.jpg"
```

Also on that page is a "relative" link to a .css file:

```
"../css/style.css"
```

So, when you save the ".html" file for the page, it contains these "relative" links. When you open your saved page in your browser, it looks for these image and css files in the folder where you saved the .html file. 
If these image and css files are not in the folder where you saved the .html file, the page will not display properly.

There are a few things you can do to "resolve" this.

1. Choose `File-->Save as...-->Webpage, complete` (or similar wording) when you save the webpage to your computer. This will save a copy of the image and .css/.js files on your computer, and modify the link in the saved html file to point to the image/file on your computer. This is not "foolproof". It seems this process will frequently "miss" some files.  In this case, you will have to manually locate and download the missing files, and manually edit the links in your saved html file to "point" to the files saved on your computer.
2. Save the html file as a "Web-archive" file (".mht")
3. Add a "base href..." line to the `<head>` section in the saved copy of the html file. Using the above URL as an example:

   ```
   http://example.com/something/index.php
   ```

   Remove the "index.php" from the webpage URL gives you:

   ```
   http://example.com/something/
   ```

   Add this to the <head> section in the saved copy of the webpage, like this:

   ```
   <head>
   <base href="http://example.com/something/">
   <...>
   <...>
   </head>
    ...
   ```

---

**Edit (2013-04-04):**

Using Internet Explorer, the best way (perhaps not perfect) to save a page that also saves the "result" of the JavaScript on the page, is to use [Microsoft Developer Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359), and then view and save the DOM source for the page.

I say "perhaps not perfect" ...

Suppose you have a webpage that uses JavaScript to "generate" HTML code that adds an image to the webpage.

If you view the webpage online, you will see the image. If you view the page source (`View-->Source`) or save the page source to a file (`File->Save as...`), you will see the JavaScript, but you won't see the HTML `<img...>` code.

Now, if you use the Developer Tools to view and save the DOM source for the page, and then open the saved file in a text editor, you will see the original JavaScript is included in the saved file, then below the JavaScript, you will see the `<img...>` code that was generated by the JavaScript.

Then, if you open the saved page in a browser, you will see the image twice. This is because when you open the saved page, the JavaScript will execute again and generate the code to show the image, and below that is the HTML code for the image that was saved to the file.

You can "fix" this by editing the saved DOM source, and then remove (or comment-out) the JavaScript. Then when you open the saved page in a browser, you will see the image only once.

---

**Edit (2013-04-05):**

It seems there may be some confusion about saving webpages 
that contain relative links, from the browser, so I decided 
to provide a working example.

Here is a webpage I created to demonstrate this:
[Waterfall-Lighthouse pictures](http://viewthis.info/superuser577187/page/)

Here is the HTML code of that page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Waterfall and Lighthouse</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="../images/imagesCAIPHDL5.jpg" /><br />
<br /><hr align="left" width="284" /><br />
<script type="text/javascript">document.write("\n"+'<img src="../images/imagesCAG7M85E.jpg" /><br />');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you view the page with the browser (I'm using IE9), 
you'll see the expected webpage correctly, with 2 pictures.

While viewing the page, you can save the source of the 
page by clicking: `View-->Source`, or by clicking 
`File-->Save as...-->Webpage, HTML only`. Then save the 
file. Either way, you'll get the same HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Waterfall and Lighthouse</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="../images/imagesCAIPHDL5.jpg" /><br />
<br /><hr align="left" width="284" /><br />
<script type="text/javascript">document.write("\n"+'<img src="../images/imagesCAG7M85E.jpg" /><br />');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But, if you view the saved file in the browser, you'll get 
a blank page, with no pictures. This is because the image 
link in the saved file, and the image link written by 
JavaScript are both "relative" links... the browser cannot 
tell the domain or path of where to find the pictures. You 
can see what that looks like here:
[View-Source](http://viewthis.info/superuser577187/page/saved-files/Waterfall-and-Lighthouse.View-Source.htm)
[HTML-only](http://viewthis.info/superuser577187/page/saved-files/Waterfall-and-Lighthouse.HTML-only.htm)

If you edit this saved file and add the line:

```
<base href="http://viewthis.info/superuser577187/page/">
```

the file will look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Waterfall and Lighthouse</title>
<base href="http://viewthis.info/superuser577187/page/">
</head>
<body>
<img src="../images/imagesCAIPHDL5.jpg" /><br />
<br /><hr align="left" width="284" /><br />
<script type="text/javascript">document.write("\n"+'<img src="../images/imagesCAG7M85E.jpg" /><br />');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, if you view the **edited** file in the browser, you'll 
get a page with both pictures displayed correctly. This is 
because the "base href" line tells the browser where to look 
(domain and path) for the "missing" pictures. You can see 
what that looks like here:
[Source-with-base-href](http://viewthis.info/superuser577187/page/saved-files/Waterfall-and-Lighthouse.Source-with-base-href.htm)

While viewing the page online, you can also save the source of the 
page by clicking:
`File-->Save as...-->Webpage, complete`.

If you view the source of this saved file, you'll see this HTML code:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0042)http://viewthis.info/superuser577187/page/ -->
<html>
<head>
<title>Waterfall and Lighthouse</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type>
<meta name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 9.00.8112.16470">
</head>
<body>
<img src="Waterfall-and-Lighthouse_files/imagesCAIPHDL5.jpg" /><br />
<br /><hr align=left width=284 /><br />
<script type=text/javascript>document.write("\n"+'<img src="../images/imagesCAG7M85E.jpg" /><br />');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you view this saved file in the browser, you'll get a 
page with the first (top) picture displayed correctly, but 
the second picture is not displayed (missing). This is 
because when saving with `Webpage, complete`, the browser 
saves a copy of the first image on your hard drive, and 
modifies the link in the saved file to point to the local 
copy of the image. The image link for the second picture is 
not present in the saved file. The JavaScript code that 
creates the second image link is saved in the file, but the 
actual link is not part of the source of the page so the 
second image link is not saved, and the second image file 
is also not saved.

Again, if you edit this saved file and add the line:

```
<base href="http://viewthis.info/superuser577187/page/">
```

and then view the **edited** file in the browser, you'll 
get a page with both pictures displayed correctly.

Another way you can save the page, while viewing the page 
online is by clicking:
`File-->Save as...-->Web Archive, single file-->Save`.

If you view this saved file in the browser, you'll get a 
page with both pictures displayed correctly. This is 
because the "Archive" format saves the first image inside 
the archive file (encoded), and saves the web address of 
where the webpage (and domain name/path) and second image 
file is located.

In all these example cases, the "result" of the JavaScript 
(the current state of the page after processing the JavaScript), 
which is the second image link, is not contained in the 
saved file, only the JavaScript is saved.

Keep in mind, that in these examples, the "result" of the 
JavaScript is very "simplistic", an almost "trivial" use of 
JavaScript. In "real" webpages, the JavaScript can be very 
complex, and can generate many many pages (limited only by 
the amount of available memory).

Now, how to save the page with the "result" from the 
JavaScript. We'll do this using Microsoft Developer Tools 
(the download link is shown earlier in this answer).

After installing the Developer Tools, and while viewing 
the page online, press the `F12` key or click:
`Tools-->F12 Developer Tools`

Then on the window that opens, click:
`View-->Source-->DOM (page)`.

A new window opens. Click `File-->Save`, and then save the file.

If you view the source of this saved file, you'll see this HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Waterfall and Lighthouse</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="../images/imagesCAIPHDL5.jpg" /><br />
<br /><hr width="284" align="left" /><br />
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.write("\n"+'<img src="../images/imagesCAG7M85E.jpg" /><br />');
</script>
<img src="../images/imagesCAG7M85E.jpg" /><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Notice in the source of this saved file, you'll see that 
the JavaScript is saved and the "result" of the JavaScript 
is also saved:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.write("\n"+'<img src="../images/imagesCAG7M85E.jpg" /><br />');
</script>
<img src="../images/imagesCAG7M85E.jpg" /><br />
...
```

I think this is what you wanted. But, there are two 
problems.

First, as before, if you view this saved file in the 
browser, you'll get a blank page, with no pictures. This 
is because the image links in the saved file, are "relative" 
links... the browser cannot tell the domain or path of 
where to find the pictures. You can see what that looks like 
here:
[DevTools-DOM](http://viewthis.info/superuser577187/page/saved-files/Waterfall-and-Lighthouse.DevTools-DOM.htm)

Again, if you edit this saved file and add the line:

```
<base href="http://viewthis.info/superuser577187/page/">
```

and then view the **edited** file in the browser, you'll 
get page with both pictures displayed.  You can see what 
that looks like here:
[DevTools-DOM-with-base-href](http://viewthis.info/superuser577187/page/saved-files/Waterfall-and-Lighthouse.DevTools-DOM-with-base-href.htm)

Here you'll notice the second problem. The first image (the 
waterfall) is shown correctly (once), but the second image 
(the Lighthouse) is shown twice. This happens because when 
the saved page is loaded, the JavaScript executes again generating an image 
link for the second image, and, the image link for the second 
image is also saved in the file.

To fix this you need to edit the saved file again, and remove 
the JavaScript (remove the `<script...> and </script>` tags and 
everything in between them). Now, the source of the **edited** 
file looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Waterfall and Lighthouse</title>
<base href="http://viewthis.info/superuser577187/page/">
</head>
<body>
<img src="../images/imagesCAIPHDL5.jpg" /><br />
<br /><hr width="284" align="left" /><br />
<img src="../images/imagesCAG7M85E.jpg" /><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Now, the saved file contains the "result" of the JavaScript 
as you wanted, and if you view the **edited** file in the 
browser, you'll get a page with only one of each of the two 
pictures, displayed correctly. You can see what that looks 
like here:
[DevTools-DOM-Final](http://viewthis.info/superuser577187/page/saved-files/Waterfall-and-Lighthouse.DevTools-DOM-Final.htm)

Now, this may seem all very complicated, but it's really not...

After downloading and installing the Developer Tools, it's 
just 4 fairly simple steps... While viewing (in the browser) 
the page you want to save:

1. Press the `F12` key or click: `Tools-->F12 Developer Tools`
2. On the window that opens, click:  `View-->Source-->DOM (page)`.
3. On the new window, click `File-->Save`, and then save the file.
4. Edit the file you saved and add the "base href" line, and remove 
   the `<script...> ... </script>`

Comment: Browsers automatically translate links when saving as HTML, so that's not a problem. OP is asking how to save the current state of page after processing JS.

Comment: @gronostaj - I have verified that for IE9 and (all or most) previous versions of IE, relative links are not "translated" as you have described. I have added a lot to my answer, including info about saving the current state of the page after processing the JavaScript.

Comment: +1 longer and most complete answer I have ever seen! =)

Answer (score 3):

Found that Firefox Add-on Mozilla Archive Format (http://maf.mozdev.org/) has Faithful Save option, which produces "effective CSS", and strips `<script>`'s (it can export to MHTML, MAFF, Complete Webpage, and convert within these).  It has done the work for a simple page with few scripts I needed to snapshot in HTML format.

Answer (score 2):

When using Firefox, you can `CTRL+A` to select all, right click the screen and use `View source code of selection`. You will see the full HTML as it is displayed, containing the runtime inserted elements and all. From the source-code window you can save this HTML to a file.

There is also [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/), a powerful tool to debug websites that allows you to inspect generated HTML code to achieve a similar result.

Comment: While I can't get it to fully look like the live website does, these options definitely helped; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

#### Saving the rendered HTML of an entire page

You can use a [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) to programmatically save the final HTML after it has been post-processed by the browser engine:

```js
javascript: (function () {
  var a = document.createElement('a')
  a.download = 'saved.html'
  var bb = new Blob([document.body.innerHTML], { type: 'text/plain' })
  a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(bb)
  document.body.appendChild(a)
  a.click()
  a.parentNode.removeChild(a)
})()
```

Minified version of the same code:

```js
javascript:(function(){var a=document.createElement('a');a.download='saved.html';var bb=new Blob([document.body.innerHTML],{type:'text/plain'});a.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(bb);document.body.appendChild(a);a.click();a.parentNode.removeChild(a);})()
```

- Live editable bookmarklet [Save HTML](https://www.taosdev.com/bookmarklet-devkit/#EQKwhgbmDODGBOBLADgFwFwAIAUAzArgHayqID2hOAlJgN4A6lmU8mYmAvJgCZmz4BbAKaFUAOgRCwqIQFEANkOGjsAcjCqqjTGzG8A7oXlkw3TplXRIQ7mIAWqAfNXbmYVgCMP5wkP2YAIWMPbABtXn5lcQ8ybgBPMURCX3gACQAVAFkAGQBdABo6TFQ45CEsVRkAD1QAemR5MCTVTABfLSYwe3ghXHN9JIMxAFUAJWyJHukhAHkPECESMezsLw6dCMERaNiEsGQywm4AYTtEeW5sMHXdWHlEWABrbBuu5HdtgDlYoTEegTIECEp3Ol2ujHaL2AQA)  (drag the `Drag me..` link to your bookmarks toolbar to create the bookmarklet)

##### Usage

Create a regular bookmark, edit it and paste the code above in the URL field. *Make sure* it starts with `javascript:` as your browser might automatically strip that prefix when copy-pasting.

Unlike the OOTB File > Save HTML this will work even if you are disconnected from the internet but still have the page in your browser. This will also work in (most) mobile browsers that do not provide a Save HTML option as their desktop brothers do.

#### Saving the rendered HTML of an iframe

If the content you want to save is inside an `<iframe>` then the first bookmarklet above will not include that markup.

A bookmarklet that saves the HTML of the fist iframe on a page.

```js
javascript: (function () {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.download = 'saved.html';
  var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
  var markup = (iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow && iframe.contentWindow.document).documentElement.innerHTML;
  var bb = new Blob([markup], { type: 'text/plain' });
  a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(bb);
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
})()
```

Minified:

```js
javascript:(function(){var a=document.createElement('a');a.download='saved.html';var iframe=document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];var markup=(iframe.contentDocument||iframe.contentWindow&&iframe.contentWindow.document).documentElement.innerHTML;var bb=new Blob([markup],{type:'text/plain'});a.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(bb);document.body.appendChild(a);a.click();a.parentNode.removeChild(a);})()
```

If the page has more than one iframe then you'll need to change the line with `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]` with a more specific selector, e.g. `document.getElementById('CUSTOM_IFRAME_ID')` or you might want to loop over all the elements in `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')` in case you want to save them all one by one.

- Live editable bookmarklet [Save HTML Frame](https://www.taosdev.com/bookmarklet-devkit/#EQKwhgbmDODGBOBLADgFwFwAIAUAzArgHayqID2hOAlJgN4A6lmU8mYmAvJgCZmz4BbAKaFUAOgRCwqIQFEANkOGjsAcjCqqAbkaY2Y3gHdC8smG6dMq6JCHcxAC1QD5qnUxaZEueGGGXefmVxAHMhVAUlEVRoACEATwAVMBCAOT8hNW9fYU0AbQAGAF13PU8BMHgAa3xkS2xsjIkKGVEAET5BaMwAHx6vHybYFuiAdURCI0wAMmmBnKFm0TGJowNO4Kp1oOjI4LEJwiF4AAlEgFkAGVLmSswAI3vLI8NMWNN77DyK6tqigBo6JhUPFkEIsKoZAAPVAAemQ8jAE1UmAAvtpdPoHPAhLhLIZVmRDGIAKoAJUuEhx0iEAHl7iAhCRyZdsI8MUxAl1RGJ7mRuPExGBkGDJgBhByIeTcbBgDl6MASeSIWBVbDy-TISrRVL8xY4gRkCBCCVSmVy9zo9XAIA) (drag the `Drag me..` link to your bookmarks toolbar to create the bookmarklet)