# Download site with js links

Tags: wget, download-manager, links

I'm trying to download an entire site:

http://givatram.org/bank/hug.php?hug=0

Unfortunately, instead of the standard `href` tag, the page uses javascript functions to generate links:

```
<tr>
<td><div align="center" dir="rtl">69821</div></td>
<td onclick='go2("69821");' style="text-decoration:none;color:blue;cursor:pointer;word-wrap:nowrap"><div align="right" dir="rtl">  </div></td>
<td style="text-decoration:none;color:blue;cursor:pointer;word-wrap:nowrap"><div align="center" dir="ltr">1</div></td>
</tr>
```

I've tried `wget` and `downthemall`, but they can't handle this kind of linking mechanism.

**How do I download an entire site with js links instead of `href` tags?**

Comment: Possibly related: http://superuser.com/questions/577102/save-website-containing-javascript-after-it-was-interpreted

Comment: I fear there will be no solution available. Those links are homebrewed (somehow pretty evil) and following them would require the downloader to have a JavaScript engine which runs the code and checks for `window.location =` or any other means of redirection. I doubt that such a program exists (especially that parsing JavaScript part).

Comment: Related question about JS links: [How to open stubborn javascript links in a new tab or new window?](http://superuser.com/questions/604705/how-to-open-stubborn-javascript-links-in-a-new-tab-or-new-window)

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to get wget to follow "javascript links". But it doesn't have to be as complicated as having a javascript engine! Is it possible to apply custom transformations to the downloaded html files, for instance "javascript='open(343)'" → "article.php?id=343" ?

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but I'd recommend using freely available R with R Studio and use the rvest package with Selnium.  Here's a good introductory tutorial:

https://ivanmillanes.netlify.app/post/2020-06-30-webscraping-with-rselenium-and-rvest/