# How do I completely download a web page, while preserving its functionality?

Tags: macos, browser, download, website, webpage

I've been trying to save [this](http://www.hostmath.com/Default.aspx) webpage using all of the methods that I know, but none of them have worked so far. The website itself has some great functionality. It is able to render MathJax in realtime, without any noticeable lag. I want to be able to use it offline, so I wanted to save it. I haven't been very successful. I'm on MacOS. Here is what I have tried so far:

1. Save as on Safari as a Web Archive (.webarchive) – doesn't preserve the page's functionality
2. Save as on Safari as Page Source (.html) – Completely messes the page up
3. HTTrack – doesn't preserve the webpage's functionality
4. Save as on Chrome as Webpage, Complete (.html) – messes up layout and functionality
5. WebDumper – gives me a "Forbidden" error
6. itsucks – messes webpage up
7. SiteSucker – messes webpage up
8. ScrapBook (firefox) – messes up
9. A couple of other things that I can't remember anymore.

I just want to save the website and be able to use it offline. I noticed something interesting, however. When I'm in Safari and I go offline, the webpage performs fine. This undoubtedly means that the webpage can run offline with no problem – I just need a way to save it properly. I suppose I could create a virtual machine, load up the site on it and then save it as a snapshot and use it whenever I want to offline, but that seems like quite a disproportionate solution for such a seemingly simple problem.

On a side note: would it be possible to save a webpage like [this](http://www.apple.com/iphone-6s/) (iPhone 6S page) with all of the scrolling animations, embedded pictures and videos and all the rest? I've only tried creating a Web Archive using Safari, but it only saved the nice scrolling animation – not the embedded pictures and such.

Comment: Its near impossible due to all the code that runs on any given page, code that pulls images and resources from hundreds of other locations not on their web server. I Use Chrome and save as (single file) MHTML, but does not always get everything but seems to be the best for me.

Comment: you could try wget from a command prompt. It will download whole websites but you can tune it to download only what you want.

Comment: The problem that ultimately cannot be addressed, is code running on the server. Most web application server runtimes execute code on HTTP GET and POST, and that code is never transmitted to the client; only its output. What you want to do is only possible if the site is written to execute entirely client-side (usually via javascript), and consumes no external data.

Comment: @FrankThomas thanks for the insight. The only thing is, because the website is able to run perfectly when I disconnect my Internet, shouldn't it be entirely possible to run it without an Internet connection and save it? That's what I keep on thinking.

Comment: @sdjuan unfortunately wget doesn't seem to work. Does it work for you?

Comment: sure works for me. "doesn't seem to work" doesn't give a whole lot to go on.    Here's the start of the man page from a terminal on my mac: WGET(1)                                    GNU Wget                                    WGET(1)

NAME
       Wget - The non-interactive network downloader.

SYNOPSIS
       wget [option]... [URL]...

DESCRIPTION
       GNU Wget is a free utility for non-interactive download of files from the Web.  It
       supports HTTP, HTTPS, and FTP protocols, as well as retrieval through HTTP proxies.

Comment: @sdjuan sorry about that. I am actually very inexperienced with the terminal and I decided to Google "wget" online. The first website that came up let you input the address and then output the HTML text of the webpage. Eisen save this as an HTML file and then proceeded to open it in Safari, and it was pretty much messed up. Do you suggest me to use the terminal instead? I'm not sure if I can do it because I know so little about it. However, you were saying that you actually succeed in with this really wants to makes me want to try somehow…

Comment: with wget you may have to script it to download things that are just links in a page. Not all content is local to the website.  Be careful what you ask for as one link can lead to another and pretty soon you may have to download the whole internet http://www.w3schools.com/downloadwww.htm

Comment: @SkeletonBow  Since you are not proficient with terminal, I withdraw my suggestion since  wget may be way too hard for you. Sorry I can't give a canned way for you to do what you want.  Good luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38824/discussion-between-skeleton-bow-and-sdjuan).

Comment: A similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/577102/save-website-containing-javascript-after-it-was-interpreted

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy thanks for the link. I read the answer but it didn't seem to work :(. This has me pulling my hair out!

Comment: I use [Firefox MAFF](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozilla-archive-format) to save pages that will display perfectly, but I never needed to use it to save a page that runs client-sided scripts, so it might not be what you need. Anyway, it's an amazing tool and nice to have :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I download an entire website?](https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website) - After thinking quite a lot about, I actually _**do**_ consider this question to be a duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/14403. As answer I can recommend https://superuser.com/a/42428. I also made [a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/14403#comment2457511_42428) myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to do this with many websites these days. And for sites that *seem* like it's possible, it would still require some Javascript experience for reverse-engineering and "fixing" the scripts that are saved to your computer. There is no single method that works *for all websites*, you have to work through each unique problem for every site you try to save.

---

A lot of websites are no longer just static files that are sent from the server to your computer. They have become 2-way interactive *applications*, where the web browser is running code that *continuously* interacts with the web server from the same page.

When you load a website in a browser, you are seeing the "front end" of the entire system that makes up the website. This "front end" (including the HTML, Images, CSS, and Javascript) can even be dynamically generated by code on their end! Which means there is code executing on the server side that **is not** sent to your web browser, and that code may be critical to supporting the code that *is* sent to your web browser.

There is simply no way to "download" that server-side code, which is why many websites don't work properly when you save them.

The most common problem causing things to break is that websites use javascript to load content *after* the initial page response is sent to your browser. The HostMath site you are trying to save offline definitely uses a back-end to retrieve javascript files that are critical to the site's functionality. In Firefox I get this error for several different javascript files when I try to open the site locally:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “file:///D:/Home/Downloads/hostmath
/HostMath%20-%20Online%20LaTeX%20formula%20editor%20and%20browser-
based%20math%20equation%20editor_files/extensions/asciimath2jax.js?rev=2.6.0”
```

See that `?rev=2.6.0` after the filename? That is a parameter that is passed to the back-end (webserver) to determine which `asciimath2jax.js` file should be sent to your web browser. My `D:` drive isn't a web server, so when Firefox is trying to load a file with a URL parameter, it fails.

You could try downloading the file from HostMath manually and save it in the right location without the `?rev=2.6.0` though. Then you would need to change the site's scripts and HTML to load the file from your drive without a URL parameter. This would have to be done for all of those scripts that failed to load.

You will hit a dead-end if there is any Javascript that makes requests to a web *service* (an API) on the host website though. This would be done to off-load computation for something that the site doesn't compute locally in the web browser, which means the back-end is *essential* to running the front-end.

Answer (score 8):

#### Browser add-on: *Save Page WE* [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-page-we/) / [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-page-we/dhhpefjklgkmgeafimnjhojgjamoafof)

A firefox/chrome add-on which is lighter than the web-recorder mentioned below, and which worked well for a subset of use cases. Configurable, flexible, and can optionally scroll pages in order to retrieve lazy-loaded content. It inlines images, scripts, fonts, etc as data-URLs producing a single big standalone HTML file.

#### Browser add-on: *WebScrapBook* [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/webscrapbook/) / [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webscrapbook/oegnpmiddfljlloiklpkeelagaeejfai)

A different approach to the same task. Can recursively download linked pages to a depth that you can specify. Highly configurable and can remove junk from pages via CSS selectors. Rewrites links to point to locally downloaded assets. On the downside doesn't have the concept of a 'project' so you cannot update a previously downloaded site. File naming somewhat random, and not consistent with files on the original site. Needs a bit of fiddling with options until it will work the way you want. One of the few options for recursively saving multiple pages on sites that require authentication.

#### Chrome extension and standalone app: [WebRecorder](https://github.com/webrecorder/archiveweb.page)

WebRecorder is a *'system for high-fidelity web archiving'* https://github.com/webrecorder/archiveweb.page — it's an open-source project which offers a free Electron-based desktop app, and a chrome extension. Scroll down to **Desktop Tools** for the app download links (you don't need to create an account in order to use the desktop app).

- https://github.com/webrecorder/webrecorder-desktop
- [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webrecorder-archivewebpag/fpeoodllldobpkbkabpblcfaogecpndd?hl=en)

> NOTE: WebRecorder will **not** save the original markup of the page in an easily parseable format; it uses its own format for storing the data which does not make it easy to pull out the bits that you need in case you like tinkering with data.

> <sup>*Note*: WebRecorder worked fine with a few medium-complexity sites, but did *not* save what was expected on some sites that are heavy on javascript, and built with frameworks such as react, angular, vue, etc (applies to all tools mentioned)</sup>

Comment: Looks interesting! I'll definitely check this out. Thanks for mentioning

Comment: I second that it looks interesting. Would love to know if @SkeletonBow had any success with it?

Comment: awesome!!! save page we works perfectly!!! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Open the website that you want to shop. Any web browser can speedy shop the web site which you are currently visiting. ...
Open the "Save web page as" window. ...
Give the saved page a call. ...
Select a vicinity to store the page. ...
Select whether or not you need the entire web page or just the HTML. ...
Open the saved webpage.**

Comment: The OP already mentioned that this doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

1. Clear the cache memory of the browser that you are using.
2. Open browser and go to the site u want to download.
3. Open the folder of the cache.
4. Download all files into the same folder where the `index.html/xml/` (etc) is.
5. Go offline, and test the downloaded page.